# Exercise 1.9 in Hartshorne - is my initial attempt a good start?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Hartshorne's Chapter 1, exercise 1.9 asks us to show that irred. components of $Z(\mathfrak a)$ have dimension $\geq n-r$ if $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal generated by $r$ elements. I think I've reduced this to a problem in commutative algebra, but I'm not sure how to tackle it.

My start: for a variety $Y\subset\mathbb A^n$ we have $$\dim Y = n-\operatorname{height}I(Y),$$ thus we need to show that $\operatorname{height}I(Y)\leq r$ if $Y$ is an irred. component of $Z(\mathfrak a)$. I tried to argue by contradiction, supposing we had a chain $$\mathfrak p_0\subset\mathfrak p_1\subset\dots\subset\mathfrak p_{r+1}=I(Y),$$ but I'm not sure how to bring $\mathfrak a$ into play here as we have $I(Y)\supset\mathfrak a$, not the other way around. How would I approach this?

Comment: Somehow I think you want to do as little commutative algebra as possible at this point in Hartshorne. Have you tried inducting on $r$? I seem to recall that working. The big tool that he's given you is the principal ideal theorem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what in this question is worthy of a downvote?

Comment: Maybe look for an argument that any irreducible component corresponds with a minimal prime ideal over $\mathfrak{a}$.

Comment: If you are set on proving the general statement for Noetherian rings then of course that's doable and again, the usual proof is by induction but in my opinion it's pretty subtle. If you get stuck you can look at Theorem 10.2 of Eisenbud's _Commutative Algebra_. But proving it in this special case of a coordinate ring is much easier.

Answer (score 8):

I want to point out that Hartshorne has given you all of the commutative algebra you really need. Let's say $\mathfrak{a}$ can be generated by $f_1, \dots, f_r$. We'll induct on $r$. The only observation is that any irreducible component $Y$ of $Z(\mathfrak{a})$ is contained in an irreducible component $Y'$ of $Z(f_1, \dots, f_{r-1})$, and in fact $Y$ is an irreducible component of $Y' \cap Z(f_r)$.

If you want to finish this off, you would have to justify a few things from the last paragraph and then use (Ex. 1.8) and the theorem (1.8Ab).

Answer (score 4):

Let our variety be $Y$ and $Y=Y_1 \cup \cdots \cup Y_s$ its decomposition into irreducible components. Then the vanishing ideals satisfy
$I_Y = I_{Y_1} \cap \cdots \cap I_{Y_s}$. Note that $I_{Y_1},\dots,I_{Y_s}$ are the minimal primes that contain $I_Y$. Since by hypothesis $I_Y$ is generated by $r$, it follows by Krull's Generalized Hauptidealsatz (e.g. Matsumura, Commutative Ring Theory, Theorem 13.5) that the height of each of $I_{Y_i}$ is at most $r$. But since $\dim Y_i = n - \operatorname{height} (I_{Y_i})$, this implies that $\dim Y_i \ge n -r$.

Comment: @user26857: So Theorem 13.5 in Matsumura is the "generalized Hauptidealsatz" or just the "Hauptidealsatz"?

Comment: I'd say it is "generalized Hauptidealsatz". (Hauptideal means "principal ideal".)

Comment: I know this answer is old, but maybe you can still help. I am confused when you say that the $I_{Y_i}$ are minimal primes that contain $I_Y$. Sure, it is easy to see that  $I_Y \subset I_{Y_i}$ for each $i$, but how do you know or how can you prove that they are minimal over $I_Y$? I have been struggling to prove this.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts: This is because the irreducible components $Y_i$ of $Y$ are maximal irreducible closed subsets contained in $Y$.

Comment: Ok, so then when we take the ideal of $Y$ and $Y_i$, since this is inclusion reversing, it will turn maximal into minimal?

Comment: @NicholasRoberts: Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This is an immediate consequence of Krull's dimension theorem which can be found [here, on page 22](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781447148289-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1355810-p174713743).

*Krull's Dimension Theorem:*
If $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal generated by $r$ elements, then $\text{ht}( \mathfrak{p})\leq r$ for every minimal prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathfrak{a}$.

Since irreducible components of a variety correspond to minimal prime ideals, we have $\dim (k[x_1,...,x_n]/\mathfrak{p})= \dim (k[x_1,...,x_n])  -\text{ht}(\mathfrak{p})$ and the theorem follows since the dimension of the variety is equivalent to the dimension of the coordinate ring of that variety.

Comment: Indeed, I found this theorem after posting this question and used it as my solution. Thank you for recording it here.

Comment: I thought Krull's Dimensio theorem says that the height of any minimal prime $p$ of $a$ is $\leq 1$?

Comment: @molocule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem). What I called the dimension theorem is sometimes called Krull's Height Theorem. It's a generalization of the result you state.