# Every irreducible component of $Z(\mathfrak a)$ has dimension $\geq n-r$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I had a lot of trouble with this question and now have written down a solution I think is correct.  Is there anything I have maybe overlooked in this proof or didn't do rigorously?  If it is correct, I'd like to leave the proof as a reference for myself and others.

> For $k$ algebraically closed, let $R = k[X_1, ... ,X_n]$, and suppose the ideal $\mathfrak a$ in $R$ can be generated by $r$ elements.  Show that every irreducible component of $Z(\mathfrak a)$ has dimension $\geq n-r$.

Let $\mathfrak a = (f_1, ... , f_r)$.  A maximal irreducible closed set contained in $Z(\mathfrak a)$ corresponds to a minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ containing $\mathfrak a$, so we need to show that if $\mathfrak p$ is a minimal prime containing $\mathfrak a$, then the dimension of $R/\mathfrak p$ is $\geq n - r$.  If any of the $f_i$ are units, then $Z(\mathfrak a) = \emptyset$, so we can assume this is not the case.  I think this can be done by induction on $r$.

If $r = 1$, the dimension of $R/\mathfrak p$ is exactly $n-1$ (by the Hauptidealsatz).  Now assume $r > 1$.  Let $\mathfrak a_0 = (f_1, ... , f_{r-1})$.  We have two cases: either $f_r \in \mathfrak a_0$ (that is, $\overline{f_r} = 0$ in $R/\mathfrak a_0$) or else not.  Suppose it is.  Then $\mathfrak a = (f_1, ... , f_{r-1})$, and by induction, the dimension of $R/\mathfrak p$ is $\geq n - (r-1) > n -r$.

Suppose $f_r \not\in \mathfrak a_0$.  Then in the ring $R/\mathfrak a_0$, the ideal $\mathfrak p/\mathfrak a_0$ is a minimal prime ideal containing $\overline{f_r}$ (easy to check that $\mathfrak p/\mathfrak a_0$ is not the whole ring).  Then the height of $\mathfrak p/\mathfrak a_0$ is $1$ by the Hauptidealsatz.  So there must be another prime $\mathfrak p_0$ such that $\mathfrak a_0 \subseteq \mathfrak p_0 \subsetneq \mathfrak p$, with no primes between $\mathfrak p_0$ and $\mathfrak p$, and no primes between $\mathfrak a_0$ and $\mathfrak p_0$.  Now $\mathfrak p_0$ is a minimal prime containing $\mathfrak a_0$, which has $r-1$ generators, so by induction, the dimension of $R/\mathfrak p_0$ is $\geq n - (r-1)$.  Hence $$\textrm{Dim } R/\mathfrak p = \textrm{Dim } R/\mathfrak p_0 -1 \geq n -r $$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exercise 1.9 in Hartshorne - is my initial attempt a good start?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311382/exercise-1-9-in-hartshorne-is-my-initial-attempt-a-good-start) I'd like to add, though, that I think the proof given in the answers to that question are similar to what you are trying to do, but avoid passing to the quotient ring $R/\mathfrak{a}_0$, which you are doing, and seems to be the cause of confusion. I actually don't really know what $\mathfrak{p}_0$ is trying to represent in your proof…

Comment: I'm gonna have a serious look at this tomorrow to make sure it's correct, but irreducible components $W$ of $Z(\mathfrak a_0)$ are in bijection with minimal prime ideals $\mathfrak p_0$ containing the ideal $\mathfrak a_0$, with the dimension of $W$ equal to the dimension of $R/\mathfrak p_0$.  So I can apply the induction argument to irreducible components of $\mathfrak a_0$, since it is generated by $r-1$ elements.  Since there are no primes between $\mathfrak p_0$ and $\mathfrak p$, we should have $\textrm{Dim } R/\mathfrak p = \textrm{Dim } R/\mathfrak p_0 - 1$.111

Comment: are we assuming a is not the whole polynomial ring?