# Proving Hartshorne's Exercise I-1.9 by using exercise I-1.8

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question is about [this solution suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1312285/185631) about solving Hartshorne's Exercise I-1.9 by using exercise I-1.8:

> Hartshorne's Chapter 1, exercise 1.9: Irreducible components of $Z(\mathfrak a)$ have dimension $\geq n-r$ if $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal generated by $r$ elements.
>
> Hartshorne's Chapter 1, exercise 1.8: Let $Y$ be an affine variety of dimension $r$ in $\mathbf A^n$. Let $H$ be a hypersurface in $\mathbf A^n$, and assume that $Y \nsubseteq H$. Then every irreducible component of $Y \cap H$ has dimension $r-1$.

Suppose $\mathfrak{a}$ can be generated by $f_1, \dots, f_r$ and no one is in the ideal generated by the rest of them (note they are not necessarily irreducible. But it seems to me that I don't need to assue $H$ in Ex. 1.8 is the zero set of an irreducible polynomial. Let me know if I am wrong). We'll induct on $r$. I can prove that any irreducible component $Y$ of $Z(\mathfrak{a})$ is contained in an irreducible component $Y'$ of $Z(f_1, \dots, f_{r-1})$. But, to use 1.8, I have to show that $Y'$ is not contained in $Z(f_r)$ and that $Y$ is an irreducible component of $Y' \cap Z(f_r)$

Question 1: does the assumption that $f_r\notin (f_1,\dots, f_{r-1})$ imply that $Y'$ is not contained in $Z(f_r)$? If not, how do we remedy this?

Question 2: how to prove that $Y$ is an irreducible component of $Y' \cap Z(f_r)$ (something might be missing here and I can't prove it at least)? It is irreducible but why it appears in the irreducible decomposition of $Y' \cap Z(f_r)$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exercise 1.9 in Hartshorne - is my initial attempt a good start?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311382/exercise-1-9-in-hartshorne-is-my-initial-attempt-a-good-start)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need to show this: if $Y'\subset Z(f_r)$, then intersecting doesn't drop it's dimension, which is just fine. (Remember, you want to show that the dimension of each irreducible component is at least $n-r$, so if it's bigger, this is acceptable.)
2. Suppose there were a closed irreducible subset of $Y'\cap Z(f_r)$ properly containing $Y$. Then this would also be a closed irreducible subset of $Z(\mathfrak{a})$ properly containing $Y$, which contradicts the fact that $Y$ is an irreducible component (and thus maximal with respect to containment by irreducible subsets) of $Z(\mathfrak{a})$.

Also, you're correct that you don't need to assume that $H$ is the zero set of an irreducible polynomial. Suppose $H=Z(fg)$: then $H=Z(f)\cup Z(g)$, so $Y\cap H = (Y\cap Z(f))\cup (Y\cap Z(g))$, and so everything works out just fine.

Finally, I'd like to point out that you can skip both of these issues: the idea is that for an irreducible variety $Y$ and a hypersurface $H$, all irreducible components of $Y\cap H$ have dimension $\dim Y$ or $\dim Y-1$ depending on whether they're contained in $H$ or not, respectively. So what you want to do is start with $X=\Bbb A^n$, intersect it with $Z(f_1)$, get a list of irreducible components of $Z(f_1)$ of codimension 0 or 1, intersect these with $Z(f_2)$, get a list of irreducible components of $Z(f_1,f_2)$ of codimension 0, 1, or 2, and continue on until you get a list of irreducible components of $Z(f_1,\cdots,f_r)$ of codimension at most $r$ (aka dimension at least $n-r$) and then you've finished the exercise.

Comment: If using the argument you recommended in the end, say $Y:=\mathbf{A}^{n}$ and $H:=Z(f_{1})$, then the dimension of an irreducible component of $Y\cap H$ is either $n$ or $n-1$, so $\geq n-1$. Then, let $W$ be an irreducible component of $Y\cap H$ such that $W\cap Z(f_{2})\neq\varnothing$. This $W$ can be chosen otherwise $Z(f_{1},f_{2})=\varnothing$. Then, again, the irreducible component of $W\cap Z(f_{2})$ is of dimension of either $\dim(W)\geq n-1$ or $\dim(W)-1\geq n-2$.

Comment: But then why does this imply that the irreducible component of $Z(f_{1},f_{2})$ also has dimension $\geq n-2$? It seems that you are suggesting an irreducible component of $W\cap Z(f_{2})$ $\iff$ an irreducible component of $Z(f_{1},f_{2})$, and I don't see how to prove it.

Comment: You're not really writing that down correctly (it's not that an irreducible component of $Z(f_1,f_2)$ is necessarily an irreducible component of $W\cap Z(f_2)$, you might need a different irreducible component of $Z(f_1)$ other than $W$), but the solution is that you just distribute unions and intersections. Remember, $Z(f_1)=\bigcup W_n$ for $W_i$ irreducible components, and $Z(f_1,f_2)=Z(f_1)\cap Z(f_2)$, so $(\bigcup W_n)\cap Z(f_2)=\bigcup (W_n\cap Z(f_2))$. @JacobsonRadical

Comment: Yes, but... how do you show that $W_{n}\cap Z(f_{2})$ is irreducible? the intersection of two irreducible sets is not necessarily irreducible, right? I am sorry if this question is dumb..

Comment: Why do you want to show that? I never claimed that $W_n \cap Z(f_2)$ is irreducible, it usually isn't (I'm sure you can come up with your own example by looking at some plane curves), and we don't need that for the argument: we only need that intersecting with a hypersurface drops the dimension by either 0 or 1. @JacobsonRadical

Comment: ok. So say $\{W_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n}$ are irreducible components of $Z(f_{1})$, and then $Z(f_{1},f_{2})=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}(W_{k}\cap Z(f_{2})$. By Exercise 1.8, the dimension of an irreducible component of $W_{k}\cap Z(f_{2})$ (if they have nonempty intersection) is either $\dim(W_{k})$ or $\dim(W_{k})-1$. No problem for now. But then how do you know the dimension of irreducible component of $Z(f_{1},f_{2})$?

Comment: So if we write $W_{k}\cap Z(f_{2})=\bigcup_{j=1}^{m(k)}V_{j,k}$ as a decomposition  into irreducible components, then we know $\dim(V_{j,k})\geq \dim(W_{k})-1$. I understand that then $Z(f_{1},f_{2})=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}W_{k}\cap Z(f_{2})=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}\bigcup_{j=1}^{m(k)}V_{j}$. So the $V_{j}$ are also irreducible components of $Z(f_{1},f_{2})$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A decomposition in to irreducible components is unique in this setting.

Comment: ah-ha! Great. Thank you so much for helping me with my dumb confusion. Great answer!